# Str.global_replace in OCaml putting carats where they shouldn't be

Tags: regex, string, ocaml

I am working to convert multiline strings into a list of tokens that might be easier for me to work with.

In accordance with the specific needs of my project, I'm padding any carat symbol that appears in my input with spaces, so that `"^"` gets turned into `" ^ "`. I'm using something like the following function to do so:

```
let bad_function string = Str.global_replace (Str.regexp "^") " ^ " (string)
```

I then use something like the below function to then turn this multiline string into a list of tokens (ignoring whitespace).

```
let string_to_tokens string = (Str.split (Str.regexp "[ \n\r\x0c\t]+") (string));;
```

For some reason, `bad_function` adds carats to places where they shouldn't be. Take the following line of code:

```
(bad_function " This is some 
            multiline input 
            with newline characters 
            and tabs. When I convert this string
            into a list of tokens I get ^s showing up where 
            they shouldn't. ")
```

The first line of the string turns into:

```
^  This is some \n ^
```

When I feed the output from `bad_function` into `string_to_tokens` I get the following list:

```
string_to_tokens (bad_function " This is some 
            multiline input 
            with newline characters 
            and tabs. When I convert this string
            into a list of tokens I get ^s showing up where 
            they shouldn't. ")

["^"; "This"; "is"; "some"; "^"; "multiline"; "input"; "^"; "with";
 "newline"; "characters"; "^"; "and"; "tabs."; "When"; "I"; "convert";
 "this"; "string"; "^"; "into"; "a"; "list"; "of"; "tokens"; "I"; "get";
 "^s"; "showing"; "up"; "where"; "^"; "they"; "shouldn't."]
```

Why is this happening, and how can I fix so these functions behave like I want them to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in the [Str](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Str.html) module.

> ^      Matches at beginning of line: either at the beginning of the
>   matched string, or just after a '\n' character.

So you have to quote the '^' character using the escape character "\".
However, note that (also from the doc)

> any backslash character in the regular expression must be doubled to
>   make it past the OCaml string parser.

This means you have to put a double '\' to do what you want without getting a warning.

This should do the job:

```
let bad_function string = Str.global_replace (Str.regexp "\\^") " ^ " (string);;
```